# multiple auto-suggest fields on the same screen

Tags: usability, mobile-application, autocomplete

I need to design a screen where the user needs to choose 2 types of values before moving to the next screen. one value from one list and the other from a different list.
The lists are dynamic, so I want to use auto-suggest feature on both.

Is there a best practice for designing such a screen ? Or is it better to split the process to 2 different screens ?

[image: This is the wireframe]
[image: The user starts typing on the first field]

Thanks

Comment: Can you add anymore detail to a system? Can you create a wireframe to show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you split the process to 2 different screens is a little bit slow. I have no objection to let the auto-suggest feature on both.

May be if you want the user keep focusing on one field, you can do like this (2 pictures but always the same screen with animation):

1. The user fills the contact field and he can validates
2. The second field slides down, becomes visible and the action button change
3. The user fills the identity field and he can validates to keep going the process...

And if he wants to change the contact field, the identity field slides up and we come back to the first picture example.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: But the auto suggestion list (of the contact field) would cover the validate contact button.

Comment: I think it's not a problem because you don't need the validate contact button when you fill the field. (If I find examples, I will share with you.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two screens (static or AJAX) or one screen with steps where the second step is disabled (or even better, hidden) until first step is successfully completed.

Basically, instead of having your user wonder what to do or creating distress or friction for the user, you can simply guide the user through steps for succesful achievement of the task. Thus, you give the user **one and only one** option. If succesful, then the user goes to the next step where he/she will have one and only one option. And so on.

While your scenario is very simple (2 tasks), the friction grows exponentially if you offer different steps on the same level, so I think that whenever you need to use some kind of *"user guidance",* it's better to use linear processes